# Need help identifying a scale

Tags: scales, tablature

The song/riff in question is in the intro of a song by "After the Burial" called "Cursing Akhenaten".

I cut a full measure out of the intro and looped it.  I uploaded it for anyone who wants to take a crack at the answer.  Here's the link - [Intro of Cursing Akhenaten](http://theannealing.com/_misc/clips/cursing_akhenaten.mp3)

Also, there are tabs for the song located [here](http://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/after-the-burial-cursing-akhenaten-guitar-tab-s30864t0) but I can't say for sure that they are accurate.

Does anyone know what scale this is?  On another, yet related, note, are there any sites that try to help identify scales provided tablature and tuning?

Comment: I believe it's G# - the chord is G# C D#

Comment: G# does not have a C, only a B# and a C#. And it does not sound like a major scale...

Comment: That reminds me of [Love, Hate, Love](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2WDhx0VHa0) by Alice in Chains.  I can't seem to determine the key of that song right now but I will investigate later today.

Comment: @Gauthier, G#/Ab maj is G#-C-D#. and it's in fact a major scale.

Comment: G#-B#-D# is G#, Ab-C-Eb is Ab. There is no C in G# major, there is a B#. B# and C are enharmonics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic), which means that they sound the same (in equal temperament) but may not be used interchangeably. These chords are major triads, not scales. What I referred to when I wrote that it did not sound like a major scale was the sample linked to in the question.

Comment: @Gauthier, please [check here](http://keychord.com/) - select G#/Ab in the list... maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I guess you refer to the piano view. I'm afraid this shows only pitches and not the real note names. It's difficult to show the correct note names on the piano, they would have needed to show all the possible names for all pitches (piano keys). Instead of C you'd have B#/C/Dbb, and so on. I know this is a bit confusing, think of it as the spelling of words. "Lose" and "Loose" have the same sound but mean different things and are used in different contexts. The piano view gives you the sound but not the spelling. G#-C-D# is the wrong spelling of the G# major triad, although it sounds the same.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a minor harmonic scale starting on its fifth. If it is the case, that is called  Phrygian major 3rd/Phrygian dominant, and played on a 7b9 chord.

Starting on an A (A phrygian major 3rd):

A  -  Bb  -  C# - D - E - F - G - A

Edited to start on G# (G# phrygian major 3rd):

G# - A - B# - C# - D# - E - F# - G#

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_mode#Other_types

I just went from the sound of it, I can't read tabs too well and I am not sure of the guitar's tuning in the loop you linked to (a score notation would help).

Answer (score 2):

I think the notes are G# A C D# E F# G#, which is part of the E major b13 scale over G# (E harmonic major = E F# G# A B C D# E).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_major_scale

Comment: I have no idea what scale this is but what I hear are these notes: G#-A-C-C#-D#-E-F#-G# perhaps more correctly written as G#-A-B#-C#-D#-E-F#-G#. 1/2-3/2-1/2-1-1/2-1-1 steps.

Comment: I wonder if this is a transitional arpeggio where there are actually 2 scales in play? Yours is the closest one to what I am hearing hence my comments here.

Comment: @filzilla: Actually, your scale is the Phrygian major 3rd scale I refer to in my answer. Only I give my example starting on A instead of G# (now edited to add G# phrygian major 3rd).

Comment: @Stefan: I - as filzilla - hear a C# as well.